# How do I pass Third Argument in hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am running my hadoop job using java Class instead of the command hadoop jar /input /output.
In this case my command looks like this. hadoop jar Main.class /input/location /output/location /thirdargument/file. 
I know how to add input path and output path in my Driver class in Main, but how to add the third argument which the input is dependent on to get output. 
Below is how I added my input and output paths.

Please help in adding the third argument.

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/path1/"));     //inputpath
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/path2/"));   //outputpath
```

Third argument addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if taking third file is possible by adding another path but you can use,

```
try{
Path pt=new Path("hdfs://npvm11.np.wc1.yellowpages.com:9000/user/john/abc.txt");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
String line;
line=br.readLine();
while (line != null){
System.out.println(line);
line=br.readLine();
}
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

I got it from:https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/hadoop-how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs

Comment: Yes. Saw this and wasn't sure of how to add this. Any way thanks for the answer. I will try implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this method. It works for me. (Apache Hadoop 1.2.1)

`FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));` // Input1
`FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[1]));` // Input2
`FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[2]));`//Output

I pass these arguments while giving the command.

`hadoop jar <jarfilepath> <class name> <Input1> <Input2> <Output>`

Comment: How did you use the file there didn't seem to be any reference to the input as well as output files

Comment: @AntarikshaYelkawar I made these changes in the java program. 
and then pass the hdfs path of the input file from the terminal of client machine.

@ Srinivas - Great. you are welcome :)